# Milk pan for induction hob

Tags: milk, copper-cookware

Traditionally, copper pans are used for heating milk because of copper's conductive properties. Does this still apply for induction hobs (obviously would need some steel in with the copper pan). What sort of pan is best to use to heat milk on an induction hob?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. Any pan that works on an induction hob will work for heating milk on it. And especially with the speed of induction, you will not notice much difference with different pans.

By the way, there is no reason to want an especially conductive pan for heating milk. Milk burns easily on the bottom when heated too quickly, so being more heat conductive is more likely to be a liability. I have personally not seen copper pans being suggested especially for milk, the traditional milk-specific pans I've seen are either thin enamelled steel or special stainless water-bath gizmos with a whistle.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to use a copper-bottomed pan is to conduct heat from a small hot-spot to the entire base (and sometimes edges) of the pan. This is especially important if using a gas stove, as (especially when using a small flame) it heats a comparatively small spot.

For induction stoves the problem is not as big as it heats most of the base of the pan. Still, when using a thin-bottomed pan on a small ring, you can see that it's hotter right above the ring than elsewhere.